# Get shorter version of for loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, optimization

I'm using Swift 3.0 and have this code for searching an item in an array as an extension of String type:

```
extension String {
    func equal(compareToArray : [String]) -> Bool {
        for s in compareToArray {
            if self == s {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

It runs fine, but my question is, can I do it better (shorter/more simple or faster)?

Okay, another similar sample:

```
func contains(compareToArray : [String]) -> Bool {
    for s in compareToArray {
        if self.contains(s) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shorter, simpler, faster

```
let compareToArray = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
compareToArray.contains("bar")
```

**Edit:**

According to your second example

<strike>!compareToArray.filter{ $0.contains("oo") }.isEmpty</strike>

```
compareToArray.index(where: {$0.contains("oo")}) != nil
```

Comment: :-) Yes, you're right. I added another example, which shouldn't be turned around. :-)

Comment: Ok, that filter takes all array members, even if the result is already true. It is shorter, but slower. I can not decide which one is better. :-) Thank you.

Comment: How is your first example any faster than OP's? Faster to type, sure, but `contains` does exactly the same thing under the hood. Also your second example unnecessarily iterates through the entirety of `compareToArray` even if `$0.contains("oo")` returns true. Using `compareToArray.contains{...}` would be better :)

Comment: @Hamish You're right. I updated the answer with an alternative closure.

Comment: Great! That's it. Shorter and at least as fast as the explicit version. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether an element belong to an Array, in Swift 3.0 this is a better way:

use :

> array.index(of: element) -> Int?

Ex:

```
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
let needle = "b"

if let pos = myArray.index(of: needle') {
  print("\(needle) is in array at position : \(pos)" 
} else {
  print("It's not in array")
}
```

Comment: I'm searching for a general optimization of a for-loop using internal functions like filter, map, ...